# Ajax.serialize() request NOT WORKING

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send my `form` values to php page in order to perform SQL requests to my server according to my `form` values. This is original php with form and ajax script:

```html
    
    <script type='text/javascript'      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="datetime-local" name="start" id="start">
    <input type="datetime-local" name="finish" id="finish">
    <input type="checkbox" name="consta" id="consta" value="tru"> Remove const
    <input type="submit" name="apply" id="apply">
    </form>
    <script>
      $('#apply').click(function(){
      var data= $('form').serialize();
      $.post('gensetapply.php', data);

     });
  
     </script>
```

And in gensetapply.php I am trying to get variables through $_POST:

```
 <?php
 $con=$_POST['consta'];
 $str=$_POST['start'];
 $fin=$_POST['finish'];
 echo $con.", ".$str.", ".$fin;     
 ?>
```

So, I am sure my ajax request is not working.
I am new to this things and have wrote code above looking to similar examples, so please feel welcome to point out my mistakes. There might be a typo cause I am handtyping it again here, not copy-paste from source.

**EDIT**:
It was working, I just couldn't see it when i refresh the page, but through devtools in Chrome (Network>Response) I. Hope it'd help some other fools like me ;)

Comment: Your using post method to post the data to server so you need to prevent the default submit by event.preventDefault();  or simple change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and is there any error in console ?

Comment: @JYoThI no errors,. just phpNotice and Warnings

Comment: show me those notice and warnings message ?

Comment: @JYoThI I just changed type="submit" to type=" button", seems to be working! Tnq u! Post as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Glad it help you :) Answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Your using post method to post the data to server so you need to prevent the `default submit`

```
<script>
   $('#apply').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data= $('form').serialize();
      $.post('gensetapply.php', data);
   });
</script>
```

**2nd :** or Simple change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Comment: Ok, this does perform code in target php, but simply with POST method I cannot ger my form values... (they return empty?) Not sure if .serialize is written correctly?

Comment: Yes it's not working for two date time columns but it's working for that check box for testing purpose comment the post method and just print like this `// $.post('gensetapply.php', data); console.log(data);` @upicik

Comment: after replacing .serialize() to .serializeArray(); I get the following output, but still can't reach with $_POST.
:
{name: "idBase", value: ""}
1
:
{name: "group", value: ""}
2
:
{name: "start", value: ""}
3
:
{name: "finish", value: ""}
4
:
{name: "constabon", value: "true"}
5
:
{name: "action", value: "send_message"}

Answer (score 1):

Here '**Apply** 'button type is `submit`. Therefore your form submits immediately. As you are handling form submission through ajax so the solution is you need to stop submitting form. You can fix it `returning false` in click event like following

```
<script>
   $('#apply').click(function(){
      var data= $('form').serialize();
      $.post('gensetapply.php', data);
      return false;
   });
</script>
```